# Have anyone tried using rule engine for dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, rule-engine

I'm still new in developing mobile apps so I'm struggling to understand how to use it since there's no examples of people using it. I want to use a rule engine for mobile application

Comment: What kind of rule engine, what for exactly?

Comment: im trying to make a rule engine to decide which pc parts that is suitable for the user so that the user can build that pc

Answer (score -1):

Looking on pub.dev, I see the [rule_engine package](https://pub.dev/packages/rule_engine). But this was uploaded 3 years ago, and will definitely have some compatibility issues with newer versions of Flutter ([Null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) for one, but other changes in the language too). I'd suggest looking through pub to see if there are packages that are A) more actively maintained and B) have more 'likes' (and is thus more popular). For splitting business logic and UI code, [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) is a very popular choice, but have a look around yourself too.